# AMFPHP + Zend Session

Tags: php, zend-framework, amfphp, zend-session

I have tried to use ZendSession class with AMFPHP, but AMFPHP uses raw PHP sessions in some of its functions and methods. I strongly need to manage all session variables by ZendSession. Is there any smart method to get it, instead of hack and modify original AMFPHP code?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the answer to your question, but did you take a look at http://framework.zend.com/download/amf ?

Comment: Thanks, but Zend AMF seems to be too slow (according to http://gfxcomplex.com/actionscript3/zend-amf-vs-amph_amfphp-ftw/), I'd like to avoid using it, if possible.